# Does the ECB provide a daily Inflation Expectations series for the Euro area?

Tags: macroeconomics, inflation, expectations

I've been searching for market indicators for Inflation Expectations. The FED provides at least two, one of those being the T5YIFR from the FRED database.

Regarding the ECB I couldn't find anything...

Does the ECB provide a daily Inflation Expectations series for the Euro area? I'm looking preferably for freely available date, but I'll take what I can... =D

P.S.: This question could be considered a follow up to a [previous question](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47079/market-measures-for-inflation-expectations-for-euro-zone) of mine on how to measure inflation expectations in the euro area.

Comment: The ECB equivalent of FRED is here https://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/home.do but they don't seem compute nearly as much stuff for convenience.

Comment: There's https://infogram.com/1p0jwz1xekpmw0fe6y331nz0pkindk9p6nq but it's not something updated. (Found in https://www.bruegel.org/2021/06/inflation-germany-the-euro-area-and-the-european-central-bank/)